# Get Principal's name in Custom Spring Cloud Gateway filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to retrieve a Principal's name as a String within a custom Spring Cloud Gateway filter so that I can pass this string to my service class to perform some logic before returning back to the filter chain.

I came across the following Global filter example where they are checking the Principal's name, but was unable to figure out how to just get the Principal's name as a String instead?

```
@Bean
public GlobalFilter customGlobalFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> exchange.getPrincipal()
        .map(Principal::getName)
        .defaultIfEmpty("Default User")
        .map(userName -> {
          //adds header to proxied request
          exchange.getRequest().mutate().header("CUSTOM-REQUEST-HEADER", userName).build();
          return exchange;
        })
        .flatMap(chain::filter);
}
```